# Reduce space between bars in bar chart of the same group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

Unable to reduce gap between bars of the same group in bar chart in SSRS 2016

I tried adjusting Point Width in custom  attribute to 0.5 but it only reduces the width of the bar but not spacing between the bars. I have enabled data labels and there are some with zero data labels which has been configure to show as spaces. So I guess the space between the bars of the same group is because of the data labels which have been made to show as space. How do I make the bars of the same group close to one another.

Comment: I think the only way to reduce the space between the bars is to reduce the width of your chart

Comment: I tried that but no luck